# Factory on AngularJS not working. Error "Cannot read property 'getInfoApi' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I am a newbie on angularJS, I'm starting to learn about factories, but my code doesn't work.

my js file:

```
angular
.module('pruebasAngularApp',[])
.factory('FacDePrueba',function($http){
    var FacDePrueba = {};
    FacDePrueba.getInfoApi = function(){
        return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
    };
})
.controller('pruebasAngularCtrl', function($scope,FacDePrueba){
    this.DatosApi = FacDePrueba.getInfoApi();
})
```

on chrome displays:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInfoApi' of undefined
at new <anonymous> (controller.js:10)
at d (angular.js:3966)
at Object.instantiate (angular.js:3977)
at angular.js:7281
at angular.js:6670
at r (angular.js:332)
at N (angular.js:6657)
at g (angular.js:6105)
at g (angular.js:6108)
at angular.js:6001
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return something from the `factory`, you will get the error because of the `factory` returns `undefined`.

```
....
.factory('FacDePrueba',function($http){
    var FacDePrueba = {};
    FacDePrueba.getInfoApi = function(){
        return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
    };

    // add return statement.
    return FacDePrueba;
})...
```